# Angular 6 SASS nesting not working at module level

Tags: angular, sass, angular6

I am working on angular 6 hybrid project. Usually we add the css depend files in angular.json in styles array.

```
"styles": [
     "src/styles.scss", 
     "./node_modules/css file"
 ],
```

As i got some style conflicts, i tried for nesting the node_modules css files inside the **styles.scss** using a parent class.

```
.parent-class {
  @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  @import "~/node_modules/xyz/styles/xyz.css";
  @import "~@aa/abc/styles/theme.css";
}
```

The above solution suggested by [sass](https://codepen.io/trey/post/nesting-sass-includes) wont worked here, any idea about nesting globally when using angular 6 to build the application.

Comment: I suppose that you trying to import CSS instead of SASS what could cause the problem. Maybe it's better to import styles globally

Comment: it's not good practice to import inside of a class like Sergy said. If you want small code chucnks you should take a look to mixins in sass

Answer (score 0):

You can add this below "styles" in your angular.json file

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "path to your sass files here such as src/scss"
          ]
        }
```

then you can import them in any sass file as follows:

```
@import 'xyz.scss';
```

etc